# How to fix assembly security error in Unity 4.6

Tags: c#, facebook, unity-game-engine

I am getting an error when trying to use Facebook Unity SDK:

> Could not securely load assembly from
>   https://integrated-plugin-canvas-rsrc.fbsbx.com/rsrc/unity/lib/sdk_4.0/CanvasFacebook.dll
>   UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object) FbDebug:Error(String)
>   c__Iterator3:MoveNext() (at Assets/Ultimate GUI
>   Kit/Facebook/Scripts/FB.cs:337)

I am aware that usually you just add if unity 4.6 to the `FB.cs`. However in the template I started with this class doesn't have this line. So how can i fix it? Here is definition of `RemoteFacebookLoader` class from my `FB.cs` file:

```
public abstract class RemoteFacebookLoader: MonoBehaviour {
    public delegate void LoadedDllCallback(IFacebook fb);

    private const string facebookNamespace = "Facebook.";

    private const int maxRetryLoadCount = 3;
    private static int retryLoadCount = 0;

    public static IEnumerator LoadFacebookClass(string className, LoadedDllCallback callback) {
#if UNITY_EDITOR || UNITY_WEBPLAYER
        var url = string.Format(IntegratedPluginCanvasLocation.DllUrl, className);
        var www = new WWW(url);
        FbDebug.Log("loading dll: " + url);
        yield
        return www;

        if (www.error != null) {
            FbDebug.Error(www.error);
            if (retryLoadCount < maxRetryLoadCount) {
                ++retryLoadCount;
#else 
                var www = new WWW("");
                yield
                return www;#endif#
                if UNITY_WEBPLAYER FBComponentFactory.AddComponent < CanvasFacebookLoader > ();#endif#
                if UNITY_EDITOR || UNITY_WEBPLAYER
            }
            www.Dispose();
            yield
            break;
        }

        var assembly = Security.LoadAndVerifyAssembly(www.bytes, );
        if (assembly == null) {
            FbDebug.Error("Could not securely load assembly from " + url);
            www.Dispose();
            yield
            break;
        }

        var facebookClass = assembly.GetType(facebookNamespace + className);
        if (facebookClass == null) {
            FbDebug.Error(className + " not found in assembly!");
            www.Dispose();
            yield
            break;
        }

        // load the Facebook component into the gameobject
        // using the "as" cast so it'll null if it fails to cast, instead of exception
        var fb = typeof(FBComponentFactory)
            .GetMethod("GetComponent")
            .MakeGenericMethod(facebookClass)
            .Invoke(null, new object[] {
            IfNotExist.AddNew
        }) as IFacebook;

        if (fb == null) {
            FbDebug.Error(className + " couldn't be created.");
            www.Dispose();
            yield
            break;
        }

        callback(fb);
        www.Dispose();

#endif
    }

    protected abstract string className {
        get;
    }

    IEnumerator Start() {
        var loader = LoadFacebookClass(className, OnDllLoaded);
        while (loader.MoveNext()) {
            yield
            return loader.Current;
        }
        Destroy(this);
    }

    private void OnDllLoaded(IFacebook fb) {
        FB.facebook = fb;
        FB.OnDllLoaded();
    }
}
```

**Update**

Looks like I was using old Facebook SDK (v4.0). So I updated `FB.cs` file and now I am getting another errors. They say something about `OGACTIONTYPE` and that unity can't load this type from `IFacebook` assembly. Check out [screenshot](http://gyazo.com/46e5ffd57a6b038140f7857f4033132c) of unity console.

Actually it says:

> Assets/Ultimate GUI Kit/Facebook/Scripts/FB.cs(212,13): error CS0246:
>   The type or namespace name `OGActionType' could not be found. Are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Here is definition of `RemoteFacebookLoader` class from `FB.cs` file that I just loaded:

```
public abstract class RemoteFacebookLoader : MonoBehaviour
{
    public delegate void LoadedDllCallback(IFacebook fb);

    private const string facebookNamespace = "Facebook.";

    private const int maxRetryLoadCount = 3;
    private static int retryLoadCount = 0;

    public static IEnumerator LoadFacebookClass(string className, LoadedDllCallback callback)
    {
        var url = string.Format(IntegratedPluginCanvasLocation.DllUrl, className);
        var www = new WWW(url);
        FbDebug.Log("loading dll: " + url);
        yield return www;

        if (www.error != null)
        {
            FbDebug.Error(www.error);
            if (retryLoadCount < maxRetryLoadCount)
            {
                ++retryLoadCount;
#if UNITY_WEBPLAYER
                FBComponentFactory.AddComponent<CanvasFacebookLoader>();
#endif
            }
            www.Dispose();
            yield break;
        }

#if !UNITY_WINRT
#if UNITY_4_5 || UNITY_4_6 || UNITY_5_0
        var authTokenWww = new WWW(IntegratedPluginCanvasLocation.KeyUrl);
        yield return authTokenWww;
        if (authTokenWww.error != null)
        {
            FbDebug.Error("Cannot load from " + IntegratedPluginCanvasLocation.KeyUrl + ": " + authTokenWww.error);
            authTokenWww.Dispose();
            yield break;
        }
        var assembly = Security.LoadAndVerifyAssembly(www.bytes, authTokenWww.text);
#else
        var assembly = Security.LoadAndVerifyAssembly(www.bytes);
#endif
        if (assembly == null)
        {
            FbDebug.Error("Could not securely load assembly from " + url);
            www.Dispose();
            yield break;
        }

        var facebookClass = assembly.GetType(facebookNamespace + className);
        if (facebookClass == null)
        {
            FbDebug.Error(className + " not found in assembly!");
            www.Dispose();
            yield break;
        }

        // load the Facebook component into the gameobject
        // using the "as" cast so it'll null if it fails to cast, instead of exception
        var fb = typeof(FBComponentFactory)
                .GetMethod("GetComponent")
                .MakeGenericMethod(facebookClass)
                .Invoke(null, new object[] { IfNotExist.AddNew }) as IFacebook;

        if (fb == null)
        {
            FbDebug.Error(className + " couldn't be created.");
            www.Dispose();
            yield break;
        }

        callback(fb);
#endif
        www.Dispose();
    }

    protected abstract string className { get; }

    IEnumerator Start()
    {
        var loader = LoadFacebookClass(className, OnDllLoaded);
        while (loader.MoveNext())
        {
            yield return loader.Current;
        }
        Destroy(this);
    }

    private void OnDllLoaded(IFacebook fb)
    {
        FB.facebook = fb;
        FB.OnDllLoaded();
    }
}
```

Comment: Updated as Solved, Thanks d12frosted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your `FB.cs` is outdated. For Unity 4.6 you should use on of the latest version of Facebook Unity SDk. You can download it on the [official page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/downloads).

Another possible problem - you modified this file. You should not do it unless you really know what are you doing.

Returning to your problem.

```
var assembly = Security.LoadAndVerifyAssembly(www.bytes,);
                                                       ^
```

This code is broken. What `,` symbol is doing after `www.bytes`?

Also for Unity 4.6 it should download `unityhash` file before it tries to load assembly. So actually this call should look like:

```
var assembly = Security.LoadAndVerifyAssembly(www.bytes, hashValue);
```

In my version of Unity SDK I have something like

```
#if UNITY_4_5 || UNITY_4_6 || UNITY_5_0
var authTokenWww = new WWW(IntegratedPluginCanvasLocation.KeyUrl);
yield return authTokenWww;
if (authTokenWww.error != null)
{
    Debug.LogError("Cannot load from " + IntegratedPluginCanvasLocation.KeyUrl + ": " + authTokenWww.error);
    authTokenWww.Dispose();
    yield break;
}
var assembly = Security.LoadAndVerifyAssembly(www.bytes, authTokenWww.text);
#else
var assembly = Security.LoadAndVerifyAssembly(www.bytes);
#endif
```

**Update**

After we discussed a problem a bit in chat we found the solution of existing problem. I am updating my question for those who might run in similar situation.

So to solve the problem OP did:

- removed **all** files related to facebook unity sdk (I mean, **all**, not just `FB.cs`, but entire `Facebook` folder!)
- download new version of sdk (it will be an unity asset package) and import it into the project
- configure facebook plugin (like use proper app id from facebook app settings on facebook developers page)

Comment: Thanks for replying, I imported a template which has facebook intergrated and that was how it was... I tried importing facebook again but then i get errors about OGactiontype.. "Assets/Ultimate GUI Kit/Facebook/Scripts/FB.cs(212,13): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `OGActionType' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?"

Oh and the comma was there because if the Unity4.6 part wasn't there to change i tried to change it using the key found in another answer on this site, but that key was most likely out of date...

Comment: I linked my new FB.cs and now i get errors about OGACTIONTYPE.. but i tried to just import the FB.cs by itself... I shall try importing all facebook again. EDIT: after importing facebook to the newest now I am getting a mess of errors. http://gyazo.com/46e5ffd57a6b038140f7857f4033132c

Comment: see above i forgot to tag you

Comment: I have a question to you. Have you just updated the FB.cs file or entire asset package? Because it looks like IFacebook.dll lacks some types.

Comment: Most probably you just need to remove old Facebook folder and import new version of asset (with checking all files)

Comment: First i tried one, then i tried importing the whole new facebook. both didn't work....I tried many times and i don't know enough yet to troubleshoot Facebook SDK even though i have read all the tutorials and seems there isn't much info on the topic anywhere.

Comment: Have you tried removing `Facebook` folder? I mean, totally with no leftovers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69947/discussion-between-d12frosted-and-mike).